# Parent custom object field value is getting NULL when I fire trigger

Tags: trigger, email

I am trying to send an email when trigger gets fired.
I have 2 custom objects

1. Quote(child)
2. supplier(Parent)

   When trigger fires user gets mail with corrosponding fields. But in those field there is a parent object field which I'm getting NULL in email.

Below is my code for your reference.

```
 trigger SendEmailCountrywise on Quote__c (after update) {

Quote__c Quote = [select id, PR_Number__c, RFQ_Status__c,RFQ_Supplier__r.name, RFQ_Supplier__c from Quote__c limit 1];
String loggedinuser=userInfo.getUserId();
User logged=[select id,name,Country__c from user where id=:loggedinuser];

List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

if(Quote.RFQ_Status__c=='Submitted To Supplier'){
if(logged.Country__c =='IN'){
 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    //system.debug('******Supplier Name'+RFQ_Supplier__r.name );
    mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{'test@test.com'});
    String body ='<html><body> Dear,<br><br> ' +logged.name+ ' submitted PR-'+Quote.PR_Number__c+ ' to '+Quote.RFQ_Supplier__r.name + '  with SLA clock <br><br> Thanks, <br><br> ZIS Support</body></html>';
    mail.setHtmlBody(body);
    mail.setSubject(logged.name+'_PR-'+Quote.PR_Number__c);
    emails.add(mail); 
    

}
}
Messaging.sendEmail(emails);

}
```

**Quote.RFQ_Supplier__r.name**

this field is getting null value which is present in body.

Comment: Hi @sfdcPro did you check whether the Quote.RFQ_Supplier__r.name contain any value after completing soql statement.

Comment: I checked, It is giving me NULL only

Comment: is this related with permission issue?

Comment: No. There is no issue like permission.

Comment: @SfdcPro
Hi, I would suggest you to put a debug statement on Quote record and get the quote id which your SOQL is returning. Check if RFQ_Supplier__c is blank in that record If yes then no value will be fetched.

Thanks!

Comment: @SfdcPro you should follow what ruchika have mention in last comment.

Comment: @RuchikaSaxena Yes. I checked the field and having null value in it.

Comment: @RuchikaSaxena  but why I'm getting that field value blank as I'm already populated that field through lookup.

Comment: @SfdcPro
 Ok...but are you sure that when you populate the field and save the record then the field still has the value ? Sometimes it happens that due to a trigger or workflow that field may again set to null. This has happened with me in one case so just suggesting you to check for those possibilities.

Comment: @RuchikaSaxena YES. That field still persists the value. It is really strange that I'm getting NULL value even after quering the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would change the Query to

```
Quote__c Quote = [select id, PR_Number__c, RFQ_Status__c,RFQ_Supplier__r.name, RFQ_Supplier__c from Quote__c 
WHERE RFQ_Supplier__c != null
AND RFQ_Supplier__r.name != null
limit 1];
```

So, it will close all the ways to get null value in code. Also, it doesn't look like that you are looking for specific record. You just want any Quote. So, using these filters would be fine.